# why is my JLabel not producing an image?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have gone over several tutorials and was wondering why my JLabel is not producing an image? I thought I had everything where I should be for the image to be displayed.  Is it possible other graphics in my program are interfering? Is there any top-down layer system java uses to determine which images are on top of each other if you have multiple ones on top of each other??

```
package scratch;

import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

//import statements
//Check if window closes automatically. Otherwise add suitable code
public class okay extends JFrame {

    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel();

    public okay(){

        jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ShawnK\\Desktop\\cat.png"));
        jp.add(jl);
        add(jp);
        validate();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame();

        okay t1 = new okay();

        window.setSize(640,800);
        window.setTitle("lets do this");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        window.setVisible(true);


        drawingComponent DC = new drawingComponent();


        ai enemy = new ai();
        window.add(DC);
        window.add(t1);

    }

 }
```

Comment: As far as I know `ImageIcon` doesn't produce an exception if it couldn't load the image. So try `new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(..))` instead.

Comment: Do you know what an instance is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just creating a plain vanilla JFrame:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
```

and you never create a `new okay()` object. Understand that it will not create itself by magic, and if you want it displayed, you have to do this in code.

As an aside, I have no idea in creation what a `drawingComponent` is:

```
drawingComponent DC = new drawingComponent();
```

since you never show the class code. Also you shouldn't set a JFrame visible until **all** the components have been added.

---

**Also**

- Learn and follow Java naming conventions as doing this will help others (**us!!**) better understand your code. Variable names should all begin with a lower case letter while class names with an upper case letter.
- Avoid extending JFrame. While this may be OK for trivial programs such as this, it does not scale well, meaning it makes your code more complicated and paints you in the corner in even slightly larger or more complex programs.
- Instead gear your GUI's toward creating JPanels, panels that then can be placed in JFrames if desired, or JDialogs, or JOptionPanes, or other JPanels. This will give your code much greater flexibility.
- Again, don't call `setVisible(true)` on a JFrame until all initial components have been added.
- Yes, you're better off getting your image as a BufferedImage using `ImageIO.read(...)` and then placing this into your ImageIcon. It's a bit safer and (I *think*) allows for better caching of images.

Comment: I updated the main args to call new okay(); which didn't produce an image still

Comment: @howevermanyitakes: you're creating an okay object but still not displaying it. Where do you call `setVisible(true)` on it? Why are you creating it **and** a separate JFrame? Get rid of the JFrame and use the okay object alone. Assign it to a variable, and then set it visible. Also your Java naming scheme (class names starting with lower case letters) suggests that while you may have gone through some Swing tutorials, you've not yet gone through some intro to Java tutorials, and that's doing things backwards. Start at the basics first as they are necessary for Swing and all other Java coding.